# insertion sort beat merge sort n<=8logn , value of n

Tags: algorithm, sorting, logarithm

I am weak in math

n<=8logn  How to solve this equation to get the value of n,

The question was from algorith "  For inputs of size n, insertion sort runs in 8n^2 steps while merge sort runs in 64n lg n steps; for which values of n does insertion sort beat merge sort?

so i figured until..

```
8n^2<=64nlogn
```

n^2<=8nlogn
n<=8logn

but how to get value of n from here , full math would be helpful and any link to learn basic logarith math is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n+%3C+8+logn

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

To figure out for which value of `n`, `8n^2` and `64nlogn` has the same value:

```
8n2 < 64nlogn
8n.n < 8n.8.logn
n < 8.logn
n/8 < logn
```

We know `m = logaX` hence `a^m = x`, therefore

```
2^n/8 < n
```

Analysis of algorithms are done to the base of 2, `a = 2`.
To solve this in Python:

```
n = 2
while 2 ** (n / 8.0) < n:
   n +=1
print("Maximum value of n for which insertion sort beats merge sort is", n - 1)
```

*References for help on this and other quizzes*:

1. http://atekihcan.github.io/CLRS/
2. https://github.com/gzc/CLRS